# How To copy data from excel sheet and paste in google chrome number wise?

Tags: python, excel, copying, webautomation

How To copy data from excel sheet and paste in google chrome number wise?

**for example:**

[image]

This is Excel Data I Want To Copy This data Number wise and paste in chrome with python

**My question is:**

How to Make Script That Can Copy Data From Excel And Paste

Comment: For reading data from Excel you can use [Pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function

Comment: I want to copy and paste in another location what I need to write?

Comment: Depends on where you want to paste it. When you read it with Pandas it is stored in a DataFrame which is basically a list. Now you can do with it whatever you want. You can write it to other files or something else.

Comment: Where do you want to paste it in Chrome?

Comment: in google sheet

Comment: Why don't you use [Googlesheets internal functions](http://www.documentsnap.com/convert-excel-to-google-sheets/)?

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use the above. You can use the [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) or maybe [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: yes but I didn't how to copy bulk data with selenium

Comment: my task is done that with python